# Pushing the node name to data model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Following my other post I am trying to make some progress but the interface does not work as smooth as I like. First of the problem is I have to do twice the double click to get to double click.

Secondly how can I push the node value after editing back to the controller and the model?

Actually I have a service that keeps the xhr json, but how can I use binding the name of the node with the scope using the '=' and I do not want to use html template or directive tag.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <div toggle-attr >{{data.name}}</div>
    <button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
    <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

    <ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
        <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>

    angular.module("myApp", []).
    controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.delete = function(data) {
            data.nodes = [];
        };
        $scope.add = function(data) {
            var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
            var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
            data.nodes.push({name: newName, nodes:[] });

        };
        $scope.tree = [{name: "Node", nodes:[] }];


    }])
    .directive('toggleAttr',function() {
      return  {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:'=',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                element.bind("keydown", function(event){      

                    if(event.keyCode === 13) {

                        event.preventDefault();            
                        attrs.$set('contenteditable', false);

                        }; 

                });

                element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                    attrs.$set('contenteditable', true);
                    element.focus();

                });

                element.bind("blur", function(event){
                attrs.$set('contenteditable', false);
                    });
            }
        };
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tekin/4pzj9xxc/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsFiddle, you omitted the `element.focus()` line (and if you're not using jQuery but only Angular's jqLite, you should use `element[0].focus()`).

However, the main problem to your directive actually working (actually changing the data, not just the displayed text) is that you need to connect the editable `div` with an `ng-model`. Here is a solution (adapted from the book *Professional AngularJS*):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
  <div toggle-attrs ng-model="data.name"></div>
  <button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
  <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
  </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
  <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
{{tree}}
```

and the JS:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.delete = function(data) {
      data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function(data) {
      var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
      var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
      data.nodes.push({
        name: newName,
        nodes: []
      });
    };
    $scope.tree = [{
      name: "Node",
      nodes: []
    }];


  }])
  .directive('toggleAttrs', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        name: '='
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        if (!ngModelCtrl) return;

        ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
          element.html(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
        }
        element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            attrs.$set('contenteditable', false);
          };
        });

        element.bind('dblclick', function(event) {
          attrs.$set('contenteditable', true);
          element[0].focus();
        });
        element.bind('blur', function() {
          attrs.$set('contenteditable', false);
        })

        element.bind("blur keyup change", function(event) {
          if (!attrs.contenteditable) return;
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(element.html());
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

I've output the `tree` value after the `<ul>` to see how the model changes when you're editing it.

[Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/souldreamer/e2k1gsha/)

Comment: I can see it is working. Yes thanks I had issues with focus(). I actually did this now slightly different. I am using a hidden input field so it is easier to create a two way binding alias and link it to value of the input which then changes the value in data. Different approach since contenteditable element has some problems like line breaks. What would be your preference?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish. The contenteditable problem can be bypassed (though not prettily, that's true), and this solution allows for one less databinding, which might be an issue if your trees get big. But if you're more comfortable with the new solution then by all means use it (until you are forced to optimize :-D). There's no *one* right way here...

Comment: YEs, I was for using less binding but saw a todo example which easily binds the value attribute to both overwrite the  node text value and also direct to database. I think I was not good at updating the database from contenteditable. I have one issue though you have raised. The focus function still gives error and I actually have a variable
`var inputElement = angular.element( element.children()[1] );
inputElement.focus();`
And this gives focus function not defined error still.